# Consultar um retorno JSON de uma API via POST em ANGULAR

Tags: json, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-routes

Olá, tenho uma aplicação que preciso receber um JSON e popular meus campos de input, após realizar um Post de cpf/cnpj. No caso em questão é a API da SEPRO, onde faço a consulta de cpf/cnpj e ele me trás os dados do cliente, estou utilizando o POSTMAN para consumir esses dados.

Porem estou tendo dificuldade para passar o método Post na minha Service.ts, fiz de diversas formas mas não funciona, consigo realizar apenas o método Get com sucesso, se alguém puder me ajudar ficaria agradecido!!!  :)

*dashboard-home.servce.ts*

```
import { HttpClient } form '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeshboardHomeService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  sepro(cpf:any){
    return this.httpClient.post(`http://{{gatway_dns}}/pessoas/v1/pessoas_fisicas/10101010010/sepro`)
  }
}
```

Comment: O que seria isso **`{{gatway_dns}}`**?

Comment: Eles disponibilizam método post na api deles? na pesquisa que fiz só achei os métodos GET. segue os links que achei abaixo [Consulta CNPJ DF V2 (Trial)](https://apicenter.estaleiro.serpro.gov.br/documentacao/consulta-cnpj/pt/demonstracao-v2/), [Consulta CPF](https://apicenter.estaleiro.serpro.gov.br/documentacao/consulta-cpf/pt/demonstracao/)

Comment: Então no Postman, para consumir os dados do cliente tenho que fazer um Post com o CPF/CNPJ, ai ele me retorna o JSON com nome completo, empresa etc...

Comment: Se você puder compartilhar isso que você falou. se entendi direito no postman esta dando certo. Confira também de onde a variável `gatway_dns` vem.

Answer (score -1):

Vou dar um exemplo básico que utilizei por bastante tempo para aprender Angular,

*ApiService.ts* - Service (Serviço)
Esse é o nosso serviço, ele irá ficar com as requisições http para a rota car da api que temos que consumir.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Car } from './car';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class ApiService {
 
  baseURL: string = "http://localhost:8080/";
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
 
  getCars(): Observable<Car[]> {
    console.log('getCar '+this.baseURL + 'car')
    return this.http.get<Car[]>(this.baseURL + 'car')
  }
 
  addCar(car:Car): Observable<any> {
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json'}  
    const body=JSON.stringify(car);
    console.log(body)
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL + 'car', body,{'headers':headers})
  }
 
}
```

*AppComponent* - Component (Componente)
Esse é o nosso componente, ele irá fazer uma injeção de dependência para o nosso ApiService e utiliza-lo para as chamar requisições http.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Car } from './car';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 
  title = 'AppComponent';
  cars:Car[];
  car = new Car();
  
  constructor(private apiService:ApiService) {}
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllCars()
  }

  // Get sendo utilizado
  getAllCars() {
    this.apiService.getCars()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.cars=data;
      })      
 
  }
 
  // Post sendo utilizado
  addCar() {
    this.apiService.addCar(this.car)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.getAllCars(); // Atualiza todos os carros, pois adicionou novo
      })      
  }
 
}
```

Agora é apenas você chamar essas funções conforme sua necessidade, nesse caso, sempre que esse componente for iniciado eu vou chamar a função `getAllCars()` para obter todos os carros, assim como você pode chamar a função `addCar()` quando o usuário clicar em um botão.

O Angular utiliza em suas requisições HTTP o [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular), *essa é uma das formas que utilizamos para trabalhar com requisições* e mais comum, os Observables no Angular, a ideia é que seja feito um `.subscribe()` para cada requisição http, como `return this.http.post`.